# Finding Range of Transformation of convergent sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$V$ is a vector space of all real convergent sequences. Define a transformation $T : V \rightarrow V$ s.t. if $x = \{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence with limit $a$, $T(x) = \{y_n\}$, where $y_n = a - x_n$ for $n \geq 1$.

Why is the range of $T$ the all the sequences with limit 0?

Comment: Hey,where's my 50 points,I answered first! I'm trying to build a rep as a teacher,here.........lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta epsilon is not necessary here as long as you know that limits are additive. Let $I$ denote the subset of $V$ consisting of sequences which converge to $0$. With this notation, our goal is to show that the image $T(V)=I$.

Let $y=\{y_n\}$ be an element of $I$. Then, $x=\{a-y_n\}$ is an element of $V$ (i.e. a convergent sequence, in this case to $a$) such that $T(x)=y$. Thus, $I \subset T(V)$.

Conversely, let $x={x_n}$ be an element of $V$, with limit say $a$. Then, $T(x)=\{a-x_n\}$ converges to 0, since $lim(a-x_n)=a-lim(x_n)=a-a=0$. Thus, $T(V) \subset I$.

Comment: Ok,so now he's got both kinds of proofs. I knew I could have done it that way, but since the N-$\delta$ proof was so straightforward,I figured why not?

Comment: I wasn't insulting your proof. But I'm an algebraist, so for me the sight of delta causes pain. I try to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: I didn't take it as an insult-and as someone who specializes in algebra and topology myself, I feel your pain.I'm glad someone posted the "algebraic" proof. But my first instinct when dealing with analysis is to go back to first principles.

Answer (score 0):

Well,first of all,what's it mean to say that $x = \{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence with limit $a$? It means that for every $\delta >0 \in R$, there exists $N >0\in Z^{+}$ such that if n > N, then $|{x_n}-a|< \delta $. Also, if a = 0, $|{x_n}|< \delta $ for an arbitrary n and $\delta$.

So now consider T(x). T(x)= ${y_n}$ . Now transform the limit of all the convergent sequences $x = \{x_n\}$ with limit $a$ under T. Since $y_n = a - x_n$ for $n \geq 1$, 
$x_n = a - y_n$ for $n \geq 1$. So ${y_n}$ = $T({x_n})$ for $n \geq 1$ and let $N = 1 $.Choose $n\geq 2$.Then $n> N$ and for $\delta >0 \in R$: 
                    $|{x_n}-a|$= $|{a - y_n} -a|$= $|{y_n}|< \delta $

This means ${y_n}\rightarrow 0$. Since this is an arbitrary value in the range of T(x), this means  $T: V \rightarrow W$ where $W\subset V$ where $W = \{ {y_n} | {y_n}\rightarrow 0\}$. Bingo. Q.E.D.